# Google Chrome can't run in xvfb because extension "RANDR" missing

Tags: google-chrome, xvfb, xrandr

I try to run Google Chrome on xvfb display, but google show error about RANDR extension. Problem is that I added RANDR to xvfb and it loaded it.
So my steps are:

1. Run xvfb server using command:

   `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 +extension RANDR`
2. This command give me output with successfully loaded RAND module

   `Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension

   Initializing built-in extension SHAPE

   Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM

   Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension

   Initializing built-in extension XTEST

   Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS

   Initializing built-in extension SYNC

   Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD

   Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC

   Initializing built-in extension SECURITY

   Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA

   Initializing built-in extension XFIXES

   Initializing built-in extension RENDER

   Initializing built-in extension RANDR

   Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE

   Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE

   Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER

   Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER

   Initializing built-in extension RECORD

   Initializing built-in extension DPMS

   Initializing built-in extension X-Resource

   Initializing built-in extension XVideo

   Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation

   [dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!`
3. Run in other terminal:

   `export DISPLAY=:1 && google-chrome`
4. Chrome outut to terminal:

   `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".

   Created new window in existing browser session.`
5. Google Chrome started in my x11 session

Comment: It's been three years, have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: @Coder Actually I don't quite remember if this exact problem is solved, but for solving task for which I tryed to use `Xvfb` 3 years ago - I used `headless` ruby gem and it was working there and also working now, so it might help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
env DISPLAY=:1 google-chrome
```